# Regex to extract Job Experience from a text

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a general regex to extract job experience from a text.

Consider the following examples and their expected outputs.

1)`String string1= "My work experience is 2 years"`

```
Output = "2 years"
```

2) `String string2 = "My work experience is 6 months"`

```
Output = "6 months"
```

I have used regex as `/[0-9] years/` but it doesn't seem to work.

Please share if anyone knows a general regex.

Comment: Does the input *always* start with `My work experience is `?

Comment: No it may differ. I just want to extract the text where the regex has matched

Comment: What do you mean you used `/[0-9] years/`? The result will only work, if you use `find()`, if you use `matches()` you need to put a regex, that matches the whole text (line), like `^.*[0-9] (year|month)[s]?.*$`

Comment: *How* may it differ and what is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternations:

```
String str = "My work experience is 2 years\nMy work experience is 6 months";
String rx = "\\d+\\s+(?:months?|years?)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/DMxOdu)

Output:

```
2 years
6 months
```

Or, you can also obtain strings like `3 years 6 months` like this:

```
String str = "My work experience is 2 years\nMy work experience is 3 years 6 months and his experience is 4 years and 5 months";
String rx = "\\d+\\s+years?\\s+(?:and\\s*)?\\d+\\s+months?|\\d+\\s+(?:months?|years?)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output of [another demo](https://ideone.com/EqpFkU):

```
2 years
3 years 6 months
4 years and 5 months
```

Comment: Now, it won't, and even support optional `and`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this regex:

```
String regex = "\\d+.*$"
```

Comment: that would also match with `34 apples`, or even with `3ajkgfajklhfajklñfh`